# Помогите разобраться с кавычками

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Есть переменная в php

```
    $mess="
     <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0; padding:0;width:100%">

<tr>
    <td ><img src="http://www.gociss.zz.mu/img/mail/1.png" onmouseover="this.src=\'http://www.gociss.zz.mu/img/mail/1_.png\';" onmouseout="this.src=\'http://www.gociss.zz.mu/img/mail/1.png\';" /></td>


<td style=""><img src="http://www.gociss.zz.mu/img/mail/2.png" onmouseover="this.src=\'http://www.gociss.zz.mu/img/mail/2_.png\';" onmouseout="this.src=\'http://www.gociss.zz.mu/img/mail/2.png\';" /></td>

 <td ><img src="http://www.gociss.zz.mu/img/mail/3.png" onmouseover="this.src=\'http://www.gociss.zz.mu/img/mail/3_.png\';" onmouseout="this.src=\'http://www.gociss.zz.mu/img/mail/3.png\';" /></td>

 <td ><img src="http://www.gociss.zz.mu/img/mail/4.png" onmouseover="this.src=\'http://www.gociss.zz.mu/img/mail/4_.png\';" onmouseout="this.src=\'http://www.gociss.zz.mu/img/mail/4.png\';" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>

</tr>
</table>

    "
```

Помогите расставить верно кавычки внутри переменно,что б правильно было

Answer (score 3):

каждый встречается с данной проблемой. Способы вывода были предложены: Visman,toxxxa, Arthur Dan'ko.

Способ разобраться:

- используйте редактор с подсветкой вашего языка программирования либо `IDE`
- используйте правила экранирования спецсимволов
- Используйте информацию для чего используются те или иные кавычки (**"** - в тексте обернутыми двойными кавычками происходит подстановка переменых, **'** - используйте для вывода текста)
- двигайтесь с лева на право. После исправления или замены кавычки окружение подсветит все ли в порядке

п.с: Использование такого кода плохая практика. Почему, да потому что такой код не читабельный и вызывает осложнения на ровном месте. Возможно это изменит поресерчить на темы MVC и шаблонизаторы

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать загнать вначале тело переменной в одинарные кавычки, чтобы не экранировать двойные...

```html
<?php
$mess= '
     <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0; padding:0;width:100%">

<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="http://www.gociss.zz.mu/img/mail/1.png" onmouseover="this.src="http://www.gociss.zz.mu/img/mail/1_.png";" onmouseout="this.src="http://www.gociss.zz.mu/img/mail/1.png";" />
    </td>
 <td style="">
     <img src="http://www.gociss.zz.mu/img/mail/2.png" onmouseover="this.src="http://www.gociss.zz.mu/img/mail/2_.png";" onmouseout="this.src="http://www.gociss.zz.mu/img/mail/2.png";" />
    </td>
 <td>
     <img src="http://www.gociss.zz.mu/img/mail/3.png" onmouseover="this.src="http://www.gociss.zz.mu/img/mail/3_.png";" onmouseout="this.src="http://www.gociss.zz.mu/img/mail/3.png";" />
     </td>
 <td>
     <img src="http://www.gociss.zz.mu/img/mail/4.png" onmouseover="this.src="http://www.gociss.zz.mu/img/mail/4_.png";" onmouseout="this.src="http://www.gociss.zz.mu/img/mail/4.png";" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>

</tr>
</table>';
echo $mess;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Так как у вас текст обрамлен двойными кавычками, то все двойные кавычки по тексту нужно экранировать.

```
<table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspa...
```

Comment: а одинарные также экранируются?

Comment: Я вот исправил,но не работает

Comment: В данном случае одинарные экранировать вообще не надо, только двойные.

Answer (score 1):

Можно ничего не экранировать, а просто заменить самые "внешние кавычки" такой конструкцией:

```
$mess = <<_END
...
_END;
```

Где `_END` - любая метка. Главное, чтоб совпадали обе метки: в начале и в конце. Эта конструкция называется `HereDoc` и работает как двойные кавычки. Если метку заключить в одинарные кавычки, то эта конструкция будет называться `NowDoc` и работает соответственно как одинарные кавычки.